# How to "NULL" a column for a user that logs out, Laravel 9

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-9

I have done this: https://shouts.dev/articles/how-to-get-online-users-in-laravel
and it works fine.

But I want to get rid of the users that logs out. Otherwise the list will be too large.
This is my lines for log out:

```
<li>
<a ui-sref="auth.logout">
<img src="/img/loader-blue.gif" class="img-responsive pull-left margin-top-2 margin-right-4 hide" ng-class="{'show': loadingState == 'auth.logout'}" width="17" height="17">
<i class="fa fa-power-off" ng-class="{'hide': loadingState == 'auth.logout'}"></i> {{_('Log out')}}
</a>
</li>
```

So, here somewhere here I want to "NULL" the column "last_seen" in my users table when the user logs out.

How?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more information to your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the logout part of your controller, just update the column to null before logging out the user.

```
User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['last_seen' => null]);
```

But I think this does not solve your issue, since the user usually just close browser without doing logout.

If you want to show just people on-line, according to the code people actively browsing your site in the last 2 minute (see the Middleware), just filter in the query in UserController.

```
User::where('last_seen', '<=', now()->subMinutes(2))
    ->orderBy('last_seen', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Roberto Braga thanks, it works but with: $users = User::where('last_seen', '>=', now()->subMinutes(2)) not "<=" Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

So with help from Roberto Braga I got it to work with this code in UserController:

```
    $users = User::where('last_seen', '>=', now()->subMinutes(2))
            ->orderBy('last_seen', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(5);
```

Users disappears after two minutes from the list when not active and reappears when activity rises. Great!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$id = Auth::id();

$user = User::find($id);

$user->update([
    'column_name' => null
]);

Auth::logout(); // logout the user
```

Comment: Hamid Raza thanks, but I think the solution I have is enough.  The column "last_seen" can keep the date, no problem. It gets updated every time the user logs in again. So when the user logs off he also disappears from the list despite the last_seen.

Answer (score -1):

Add users model $fillable = ['last_seen',...];

Comment: Ramil Huseynov -- Have that already.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).